# Proof that $x^2+y^2+z^2=7$ does not have a rational solution

Tags: diophantine-equations, irrational-numbers

Proof that $x^2+y^2+z^2=7$ does not have a rational solution.

I figured out that I have to prove it by reductio ad absurdum, but I try and can't still found how to prove it. Or using proof by infinite descent but I have no idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any such rational solution yields a primitive integral solution to
$$X^2+Y^2+Z^2=7W^2.$$
Now reducing mod $8$ shows that $W$ is even, but then also $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are even, a contradiction.

Comment: This was the solution I was about to give! +1 from me.